# Meteor - Search Collection to find close enough results

Tags: search, collections, filter, meteor, find

I can achieve search results using

Session.set and Session.get. But this will result only the exact match. There I tried

```
Collection.find({content:{"$regex":"^" + currentSearch + "\\b","$options":"i"}});
```

and this worked for me, my current requirement is to display all matching results.

I have a content in DB "I am looking for a result"

If I search for "looking" or "result", I need "I am looking for a result" to be displayed.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap the search with regex metacharacters, like this:

```
Collection.find({content:{"$regex": ".*" + currentSearch + ".*", "$options":"i" }});
```

The dot (or period) matches any character but line breaks, and the * indicates "0 or more". So, "0 or more of any character before and after the search term" would be the resulting regex.

Comment: No problem :) By the way, you might want to check out the [easy-search](https://github.com/matteodem/meteor-easy-search) package if you're planning on doing more search-related things. There's support for elastic search and all that good stuff.